# Haskell - an infinite List which is divisible by every number of a given List

Tags: list, haskell

I am still a beginner in Haskell and currently I am trying to create a function in which i generate an infinite list from which I (if I use take 10 for example) take the first ten number, which are divisible by another list, which is given.

Here is my idea:

```
myCode :: [Int] -> [Int]
myCode (a:as) = [ x | x <- [0..] , x `mod` a == 0 , x `mod` myCode as ==0]
```

As you may have notices is that I am trying to solve it through recursion, however I always get the error "Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘[Int]’ " 
I am kinda at a loss, because I wouldn't know how else to solve this particular problem.

Comment: So they should be dividable by *all* elements in the given list?

Comment: What do you hope this recursion to accomplish? Give some example outputs that the function should yield once it works!

Comment: Sorry about that, they should be all number that are divisible by any number of the given list for example take 5 (myCode[2,5]) would get me the List [2,4,5,6,8]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use recursion here: simply use [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:all) (or [`any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:any)) as condition:

```
alldiv :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool
alldiv l b = all (\n -> b `mod` n == 0) l

myCode :: [Int] -> [Int]
myCode as = [ x | x <- [0..] , alldiv as x]
```

You can rewrite `alldiv` to:

```
alldiv :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool
alldiv l b = all ((==) 0 . mod b) l
```

or even attach it locally to `myCode`:

```
myCode :: [Int] -> [Int]
myCode as = [ x | x <- [0..] , alldiv x]
    where alldiv b = all ((==) 0 . mod b) as
```

Finally you do not need list comprehension, you can simply use [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:filter):

```
myCode :: [Int] -> [Int]
myCode as = filter alldiv [0..]
    where alldiv b = all ((==) 0 . mod b) as
```

## EDIT

Since it is sufficient that it one element in the list is a divider, you only need to replace `all` with `any`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, however in this case I am looking for all Numbers which are divisible by either numer and not ALL numbers of the List for example take 4 (myCode[2,3]) would be [2,3,4,6] sorry for not specifying clearly enough

Comment: However through your coment I still did learn a lot of functions I should research :) Thanks a bunch

Comment: @HenrikBaumann: in that case you simply need to replace `all` with `any`.